# "dict" being interpreted as a "list" and I can't tell why

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I have a strange problem and I can't seem to find a solution. I'm creating a Python app that sends a get request to an endpoint, fetches some data in JSON format and processes it to insert it into a database later. I have to classes, one is like APIClient, and the other is just a namespace to hold some methods to transform the data, let's call it APITransform.

There is a problematic method in APITransform, so here's the code.

```
#api.py module"
class APITransform:
 ...
 @staticmethod
 def flatten(data:dict, method:str):
    if method == "some flattening method from a config file":
       return list(data.values())

 ....

class APIClient:
 ....

 def get_data():
   ....
   response = requests.get(URL, headers, params)
   json_resp = response.json() 
   json_resp = APITransform.flatten(
        json_resp, "some flattening method from a config file")

#main.py module 
from api import APIClient

api_client = APIClient()
api_client.get_data()
```

The error traces to APITransform.flatten() with the message:

```
return list(data.values())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

EDIT: The strange thing is that If I print the type of `json_resp` object before passing it to `APITransform.flatten()` in `get_data()`, I get two outputs in two lines: `<class dict>` and `<class list>`. It's like get_data() is being called twice, but I searched it in the entire project, I can only find it in two places, the definition in APIClient and call in main.py. I'm out of debugging ideas.

Anyone with an idea? Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback.

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @user56700 it's hard to create a reproducible example, but it traces to the APITransfrom.flatten() with the message: return list(data.values())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Have a close look at the example. The return of `.json()` is a `list[dict]`: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Comment: @dROOOze That's true, but please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

the code can raise such an error if the result of the json which is returned from a server, is a list, for example, if the `response` (from the server) is something like `"[1,2,3]"` or any other json list, the `json_resp` variable would be a list, that of course has no values() function. make sure the server returns the data in proper format or use an if statement to check before passing to the `flatten` function.